# Using HTML flex/CSS in a nav-bar to display logo in the left, menu to the right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to code a responsive horizontal nav bar using flex-display (see attached pic for final project), but I can't get the vector logo sized down and to the left. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <div class="menuBar">
       <ol id="navList">
         <li><img id="menuLogo" src="img/fullLogo.png"></li>
         <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
         <li><a href="approach.html">APPROACH</a></li>
         <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
         <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
         <li><a href="meetUs.html">MEET US</a></li>
         <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
       </ol>
    </div>
</nav>
```

As you can see, I've tried putting the logo (the img file) in the  to try and line it up. And here's my CSS:

CSS:

```
nav{
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

#navList{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#menuLogo{
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
}

#navList li{
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

The logo (img file) keeps pushing the last

(Contact) off the right side of the page. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can take logo out of `ol` and do somehing like this

```css
.menuBar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: white;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px;
}
ol {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="menuBar">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <ol id="navList">
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="approach.html">APPROACH</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="meetUs.html">MEET US</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
     </ol>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex:1;` on the first `li` .

```css
#navList {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#navList li:first-of-type {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0
}

#navList li {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin: 1em 1em 0;
  /* eventually : */
  white-space: nowrap;
}


nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)) bottom repeat-x;
  background-size: 100% 3px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="menuBar">
       <ol id="navList">
         <li><img id="menuLogo" src="http://dummyimage.com/185x70/FF0&text=LOGO"></li>
         <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
         <li><a href="approach.html">APPROACH</a></li>
         <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
         <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
         <li><a href="meetUs.html">MEET US</a></li>
         <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
       </ol>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it working. One thing that might be messing me up: 

I have hidden the nav bar <img> when the screen is small (img{display:none}), and when the screen is resized for a desktop, I use a media query to display it as 'flex'. (img{display: flex}).

Comment: @brandonstiles you should hide the first li (img will be hidden too). is it the white-space messing up your thing ?

Comment: @GCyrillius I just can't figure out why it's not working! Here's a link to what I wanted the final product to look like: 

http://scrapd.nl/old.html

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @brandonstiles there is much css there to go through , maybe a codepen with only the menu and css related would do. --- something like this ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RazvYL